# Unmute D-Command on startup

Tags: pro-tools, monitoring

Every time I start up the D-Command the main output is muted by default.  How can I make it start up unmuted?

Comment: I have no clue what a D-command is.

Comment: @neilfein: It's a Pro Tools control surface.  http://www.avid.com/US/products/ICON-D-Command-ES

Comment: This question should probably have the pro-tools tag. (I don't have enough rep to retag yet.)

Comment: @neilfein: Good point.  Retagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand this behavior is by design and cannot be changed.

It's to prevent sending sudden spikes of voltage into monitors or amplifiers, and to protect your ears in the case of something like feedback that you didn't expect.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any supporting documentation links I could look at?